# EF6 not using the Foreign key specified in annotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've two tables in my DB, Countries and States.  Using the Code first approach, I created the following two entities:

```
public partial class Country
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)] 
    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string Code { get; set; }  //Country Code

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }  // Country Description

    [ForeignKey("Code")]
    public IList<State> States { get; set; }

}

public partial class State
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)] 
    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }  //Country Code

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string Code { get; set; }  //State Code

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Description { get; set; }  //State Description

    [ForeignKey("CountryCode")]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

In the State class, I've a foreign key called CountryCode, which is what I'm expecting EF to use to join these two entities.  But it is not.  Instead, it is joining the Code field in Country class with Code field in State class.  What am I doing wrong here.  Below is the sql it generated:

```
SELECT 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[Code] AS [Code], 
[Project2].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project2].[CountryCode] AS [CountryCode], 
[Project2].[Code1] AS [Code1], 
[Project2].[Description1] AS [Description1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Code] AS [Code], 
    [Limit1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Extent2].[CountryCode] AS [CountryCode], 
    [Extent2].[Code] AS [Code1], 
    [Extent2].[Description] AS [Description1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[CountryCode] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
    FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[Code] AS [Code], 
        [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Countries] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Code] = @p__linq__0 ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[States] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[Code] = [Extent2].[Code]
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[Code] ASC, [Project2].[C2] ASC
```

Comment: Have you tried listing out the key as a primitive type with the complex type as a virtual?  IE public string CountryCode {get;set;} and then public virtual Country Country {get;set;} respectively, inside the State class?

Comment: Strange.  It works if I change [ForeignKey("Code")] in Country class to [ForeignKey("CountryCode")].  That is not how it works according to http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem:

- Remove the `ForeignKey` annotation from the `States` property.
- Add an `InverseProperty` annotation to the `Country` property.

**BEFORE:**

```
public partial class Country
{
    /* other properties */

    [ForeignKey("Code")]
    public IList<State> States { get; set; }
}

public partial class State
{
    /* other properties */

    [ForeignKey("CountryCode")]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

**AFTER:**

```
public partial class Country
{
    /* other properties */

    public IList<State> States { get; set; }
}

public partial class State
{
    /* other properties */

    [ForeignKey("CountryCode")]
    [InverseProperty("States")]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```